# "Save link as" Event

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

Suppose on a web page, there's a link that lets the user download the current state of the application in some file format like so:

```html
<a href="example.com/download/url" id="download-link">Download</a>
```

I can easily listen to the click event and make sure that the most recent state is pushed to the server before the download request is made, like so:

```js
$('#download-link').on('click', function(event) {
   event.preventDefault();
   pushStateToServer().done(function(){
     window.location.href = event.target.href;
   });
});
```

This, however, does not work if the user right clicks the link and selects "Save link as".

Is there any way for me to catch this event?

Comment: _mousedown, mouseup, click (left), contextmenu (right)_, right click is _button_ `2`

Answer (score 4):

No, I'm pretty sure there is no way you can achieve this.

The only thing you can catch is `contextmenu` which is when you right-click on the link, but there isn't a way to find out what link in the context menu was clicked.

This is as close as you're gonna get.

```
$('#download-link').on('contextmenu', function(event) { ... });
```